# Android HWUI error after closing an app

Tags: java, android, hwui

When I close my app I receive the following error in the Android Monitor. I tried some solutions I found but none seams to work. I'm using Android Studio.

---

```
    E/OpenGLRenderer: SFEffectCache:clear(), mSize = 0
    E/libEGL: ------------------------------------------------
    E/libEGL: HWUI Context(-2092265728) Damaged Report-Shader
    E/libEGL: HWUI   Shaders(3):
    E/libEGL: HWUI     Unit 0) Handle(17)
    E/libEGL: HWUI     Unit 1) Handle(19)
    E/libEGL: HWUI     Unit 2) DAMAGED Handle(24)
    E/libEGL: ------------------------------------------------
    E/libGLESv2: HWUI Protection: wrong calling from app context F:ES2-glDeleteShader, handle(24)
    E/libEGL: ------------------------------------------------
    E/libEGL: HWUI Context(-2092265728) Damaged Report-Shader
    E/libEGL: HWUI   Shaders(3):
    E/libEGL: HWUI     Unit 0) DAMAGED Handle(17)
    E/libEGL: HWUI     Unit 1) Handle(19)
    E/libEGL: HWUI     Unit 2) Handle(24)
    E/libEGL: ------------------------------------------------
    E/libGLESv2: HWUI Protection: wrong calling from app context F:ES2-glDeleteShader, handle(17)
    E/libEGL: ------------------------------------------------
    E/libEGL: HWUI Context(-2092265728) Damaged Report-Shader
    E/libEGL: HWUI   Shaders(3):
    E/libEGL: HWUI     Unit 0) Handle(17)
    E/libEGL: HWUI     Unit 1) DAMAGED Handle(19)
    E/libEGL: HWUI     Unit 2) Handle(24)
    E/libEGL: ------------------------------------------------
    E/libGLESv2: HWUI Protection: wrong calling from app context F:ES2-glDeleteShader, handle(19)
```

Comment: Hi, Joāo. So, you've tried "some solutions you found"? We need specifics. List out what you've tried, and what the results were of each. We also need to see the relevant part of your code, without which we can do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are updating your ui (possibly some animation or graphics related work) and you are not cancelling it, This can happen if some work is pooled to opengles hardware but the recepient of that updated is probably gc'ed or non existent